# How to calculate percent of sum of all unique id in one table to sum of all unique id in another table for every day of certain period?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

Could you help me to write a query to calculate percent of sum of all unique id in one table to sum of all unique id in another table for every day of certain period?

I've got two tables (a and p) with two columns in each other (user_id and date). The second table is shorter.

```
Table a
user_id    date
1          01.01.2018
2          01.01.2018
3          02.01.2018
1          03.01.2018
2          04.01.2018
```

Table2

```
user_id   date
1         01.01.2018
3         02.01.2018
2         04.01.2018
```

Expected view (for example between 01.01.2018 - 04.01.2018:

```
date        percent
01.01.2018    50%
02.01.2018    100%
03.01.2018    0%
04.01.2018    100%
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: what percent of sum you need ??   .., how the result is calculated ??.. explain better

Comment: @scaisEdge , on 01.01.2018 there was one user of two. It is 50%
on 02.01.2018 there were 1 user of one. It is 100%
On 03.01.2018 there were no users in another table. It is 0

Comment: i have posted  first answer  hope is waht you are looking for  ..

Comment: Shouldn't user_id appear in your expected view - or how would your expected view look if 2 also appeared in table 2 with a date of 01.01.2018?

Comment: @P.Salmon. No. In expexted view should be only 2 figures each date (number and date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem description is not much clear but it seems to me you try to below things. use join and aggregate funtion

```
  select a.date, count(distinct p.user_id) / count(distinct 
  p.user_id)*100 as percent from a 
  left join p on a.user_id = p.user_id 
  where a.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04' 
  group by a.date
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But how should I set a time period?

Comment: then you need where clause

Comment: I used your variant with little changes. But I thing it calculates wrong. What should I change?

     select a.date, 
    count(distinct p.user_id) / count(distinct p.user_id)*100 as percent
    from a left join p
    on a.user_id = p.user_id 
    where a.date between '2018-01-01' and '2018-01-04'
   group by a.date;

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков ok then will i change that in answer

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков if it helps then accept answer i changed your updated

Answer (score 0):

You could join the group by count

```
    select t.date, ifnull(b.date,0)100/t.count(*)
    from (
    select date, count(*) 
    from table_a 
    group by date
    ) t 
    left join table b on b.date  = a.date
```

Comment: thanks. What is "t" in your answer?

Comment: asnwer update  .. t .  (wrong a after subquery)   is the table alias  name for the table generated  by subquery  ...